# Rename column containing substring - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, substring

I need to rename columns in containing specific substring. In my case I am using data with columns that are named a specific date dd/mm/yyyy. I want to rename the column based on the yyyy of the column name (eg. 30/06/2020 rename FY1920).

Approach I have tried is as follows:

```
d.rename(columns = lambda x: 'FY1920' if x.endswith('2019') else x)
```

also tried:

```
d.columns.str.contains('2019')
d.rename(lambda x:'FY1920' if any(k in x for k in keys) else x, axis=1)
```

I am sure there is an easy way. Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: You need to assign the result back: `d = d.rename(columns = lambda x: 'FY1920' if x.endswith('2019') else x)`, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rename` does not work in-place, you need to assign the result back:

```
df = pd.DataFrame('x', index=[0, 1], columns=['1/1/2019', '1/1/2020'])
df

  1/1/2019 1/1/2020
0        x        x
1        x        x
```

```
df2 = df.rename(columns=lambda c: 'FY1920' if c.endswith('2019') else c)
df2
 
  FY1920 1/1/2020
0      x        x
1      x        x
```

---

Another option is to use `set_axis` or direct assignment:

```
df.set_axis(
    labels=['FY1920' if c.endswith('2019') else c for c in df], 
    axis=1, 
    inplace=True)
# or 
# df.columns = ['FY1920' if c.endswith('2019') else c for c in df]

df

  FY1920 1/1/2020
0      x        x
1      x        x
```

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. Very helpful! :) Seems I was close.